# exsheets \vary with tikz \coordinate

Tags: tikz-pgf, exsheets

I'm trying to use exsheet's `\vary` command in a `tikzpicture`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{exsheets}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (point) at (0, \vary{1}{-1});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

but I get an error:

```
! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   \tex_long:D 
l.6 \coordinate (point) at (0, \vary{1}{-1})
                                            ;
```

I've tried several different versions of this, including:

```
\coordinate (point) at (\vary{0,1}{0,-1});
\coordinate (point) at \vary{(0,1)}{(0,-1)};
\node at (0, \vary{1}{-1}) {};
\node at (\vary{0,1}{0,-1}) {};
```

But they all give me errors of one form or another. How do I get the `\vary` command to work with TiKZ?

Comment: `\vary` is not expandable which probably is a problem. Try `\vary{\coordinate (point) at (0,1);}{\coordinate (point) at (0,-1);}`

Comment: Yes, that works, thanks! Pity it has to be so repetitive, but at least it produces the right result.

Comment: maybe `\newcommand\varycoord[3]{\vary{\coordinate (#1) at (#2);}{\coordinate (#1) at (#3);} }` and `\varycoord{point}{0,1}{0,-1}` then?

Comment: Fair enough. Yes, creating a new command would always work.

Comment: @clemens Do you want to write up an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@clemens already answered this question in the comments.

> \vary is not expandable which probably is a problem. Try \vary{\coordinate (point) at (0,1);}{\coordinate (point) at (0,-1);}

which solves the problem as the choice is now explicit coordinates that can be parsed.